# Is it possible to use wildcard on a json path in json_extract function?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have to extract the value from the path `'$.quotes.NAME.cheapest.cost'`, the NAME changes but the rest of the path is the same. Is it possible to use a wildcard or something like `*`?

Comment: It's really strange with `JSON_EXTRACT`. I can use `JSON_EXTRACT(`jsondata`, '$.*')` in `SELECT ... FROM` but it is not possible in `WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`jsondata`, '$.*') IN ('31')`. Even tough I try to use `31` (integer), `'31'`, `'"31"'` but they are all no return value. Replace `.*` inside `WHERE` to something exists in the value like `."keyId"` it works. This means if I have many JSON object keys then I have to use other way to search or iterate on all keys.

Answer (score 1):

No, json path support in Presto is very limited (unlike one which was added to [Trino](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html)). You need to use alternative approaches via casting needed stuff to `MAP`'s and `ARRAYS`'s and processing it with `unnest` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71827295/2501279) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67128518/2501279).